# Switch TabBar Item from separate Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

In my application I have TabBar Controller and Navigation Controller with one View Controller that are not connected to each other.

I use TabBar Controller as root vc in my app, and other Navigation Controller as a side menu which slides in on top of TabBar Controller. To make menu I used this repo - [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu)

**Question:** How can I switch TabBar item from that Menu I have? Simply calling `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1` inside MenuViewController does nothing.

**What I have done so far:**

- As a temporary working solution I have used Notification Center to register switching of tabs in my ViewController that is presented by TabBar Controller, but I don't think this is great idea, as I have 5 VC in it and only in one of them I have func that switches tabs.
- Calling TabBar by Storyboard ID and then working with it also didn't help.
- Extending `UITabBarController` class also didn't help (possibly did smth wrong)

Comment: If you are downvoting kindly explain reason. Maybe my question is not clear or so?

Comment: Share some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app I have `MainTabBarController` which is almost always is root. I use static variable to access shared one.

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    // MARK: - Variables
    public static var shared: MainTabBarController? {
        set {
            UIApplication.shared.window.rootViewController = newValue
        }

        get {
            guard let mainTabBarController = UIApplication.shared.window.rootViewController as? MainTabBarController else { return nil }

            return mainTabBarController
        }
    }
}
```

So I can change it any time.

```
MainTabBarController.shared?.selectedIndex = 0
```

---

*Simply calling tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1 inside MenuViewController does nothing.*

This shouldn't work, because of your hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your solution didn't quite work for me, but put me on correct path. I came up with this: `if let tabBarController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController { }` and it allows me to get access to my TabBarController anywhere in code. Thanks!